# Manipulating classes / adding event handlers to Document Fragments not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In creating a Document Fragment, I have encountered an issue with (seemingly) both manipulating the fragment's class list and attaching an event handler to the fragment, using jQuery.

I *can* however query the fragment AND append elements to it, [as you can see in my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/ogto526s/1/)

Here's my code:

```
//Test elem
var elem = {
    "name" : "Dual Intel Xeon E5 4603 v2 Processor, 2.2GHz 4 core / 8 thread SMT",
    "cores" : 4,
    "threads" : 8,
    "base" : 2.2,
    "turbo" : 2.2,
    "price" : 1000
}

//Create document fragment using an HTML string 
//(backslashes are for escaping carriage returns)
var fragment = createDocFrag
(
    "<div class='product'>\
        <div class='collapsed'>\
            <p class='name'></p>\
            <p class='price'><span>£</span></p>\
        </div>\
        <div class='expanded'>\
            <ul>\
                <li class='base'><span> GHz Base</span></li>\
                <li class='turbo'><span> GHz Turbo</span></li>\
                <li class='cores'><span> Cores</span></li>\
                <li class='threads'><span> Threads</span></li>\
            </ul>\
        </div>\
    </div>"
);

//These work - the appended elements have these updated properties
$(fragment).find(".name").append(elem.name);
$(fragment).find(".base").prepend(elem.base);
$(fragment).find(".turbo").prepend(elem.turbo);
$(fragment).find(".cores").prepend(elem.cores);
$(fragment).find(".threads").prepend(elem.threads);
$(fragment).find(".price").append(elem.price);

//This doesn't work - the class doesn't appear inside the element in the DOM
if ($(".product.current").length === 0) {
    $(fragment).addClass("current");
}

//Neither does this - no class in the DOM, and the click event isn't registered
$(fragment).click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
});

//Append fragment to dom
$("body").append(fragment);

//Function for creating document fragment from an HTML String
function createDocFrag(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment is not really added to the dom, but its contents are so bind the handler to the `.product` element which is the root element in your fragment

```
$(fragment).find('.product').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6w16ecac/)

Comment: Thanks very much! Works perfectly